# Gcc Plugin - Adding a label to the generated assembly

Tags: gcc, gcc-plugins

I'm trying to use a plugin to generate a label with the following code:

```
tree lab = build_decl (gimple_location (gsi_stmt (gsi)),
LABEL_DECL, NULL_TREE, void_type_node);
DECL_ARTIFICIAL (lab) = 0;
DECL_IGNORED_P (lab) = 1;
DECL_CONTEXT (lab) = current_function_decl;
DECL_NAME(lab) = get_identifier("test_text");

location_t loc = gimple_location (gsi_stmt (gsi));
tree label = create_artificial_label (loc);
gsi_insert_before (&gsi, gimple_build_label (lab), GSI_SAME_STMT);
```

While this works when I try to generate code for my intel processor, if I run this plugin in a cross-compiler for arm the labels' names are changed to a local symbol with a random name. For example, instead of obtaining "test_text:" I get ".L4:". Also, an additional instruction is added.

Below is an example of the code generated without the label generation code enabled.

```
ldrb    r3, [fp, #-5]   @ zero_extendqisi2
add r2, r2, r3
movw    r3, #:lower16:b1
movt    r3, #:upper16:b1
str r2, [r3, #4]
```

And now, it follows the code generated using the first shown code (generating a label in the tree and gimple representations). You can see that the test_text label was subsituted by .L5 and that an add instruction was added below the label. How is this possible?

```
 ldrb   r3, [fp, #-5]   @ zero_extendqisi2
 add    r2, r2, r3
.L5:
 add    fp, fp, #4
 movw   r3, #:lower16:b1
 movt   r3, #:upper16:b1
 str    r2, [r3, #4]
```

I'm running my plugin after the CFG pass. Also, I'm using Linaro cross-compiler arm-eabi-gcc version 6.3.1.

Best Regards

Edit 1:
Also found, by using -fdump-tree-optimized, that until this stage everything is fine. Partial output of the *.optmized file:

`<bb 4>:
  _8 = i_2 % 3;
  _9 = _8 == 0;
 test_text:
  div_3 = _9;
  _11 = i_2 % 5;`